# Django and Ajax, get the Foreign Key values oreturned by Json serializer

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, serialization

so here's my problem.

I have a search bar and when i click the search button i send an ajax request to retrieve all the items that contains the word in the search input. The problem is that when i append the retrieved items to the Table,two of  my fields are represented as an id, not with a name (because they have ForeignKeys)

Models.py

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
code = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
category = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
description = models.TextField()
value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    limit_choices_to={'is_superuser': True},)
brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)
model = models.CharField(max_length=25)
serial = models.CharField(max_length=30)
status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
image = CloudinaryFieldFix('image', null=True, blank = True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{0} {1}'.format(self.code, self.description)
```

Inventory.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnSearch").click(function(){
    description = $("#search").val();
    $.ajax({
    url: '/inventary/list/searched_equipment',
    data: {
        'description' : description
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var equipment = data;
        if (equipment.length==0){
            $("#tblEquip").empty();
            alert("No items");
        }
        else{
            for (var i=0;i<equipo.length;i++){
               $("#tblEquip").empty();
               alert(equipo[i]["fields"]["category"]);
            }
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Views.py

```
def searched_equipment(request):
description = request.GET.get('description')
items = Inventory.objects.filter(description__icontains=description)
html = seralizers.serialize('json',items)
return HttpResponser(html)
```

Also, i tried to use the Wadofstuff Full Serializer to get the full data of that other model object, not only the id, but i cant make it work.

```
print(serializers.serialize('json',Inventory.objects.all(),indent=4,relations = 
('category','user',)))

 File "C:\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 176, in dump
default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).iterencode(obj)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'relations'
```

Comment: You should use Django REST Framework, which allows you to define more complex serializers including following foreign keys.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you! i will check the REST Framework (never worked with it thought) but see if that solves my problem